# multiple use of one mm table in TCA

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm using the extensions news and eventnews, so if have two different "types" of news now.

The news extension comes with the fields related and related_from.

I want to have also fields related_event and related_event_from.
The original related fields should store relations to news which are just news, the new fields relations to news which are events. 
The difference is made in field "is_event", so I added the foreign_table_where clause to the TCA.

For storing the data I have to use the same mm table. Unfortunately on saving only the second field is respected, the first one is not.

How can I achieve storing both? Will I need to use a TCA hook or is it possible with standard TCA settings or ..?

My TCA as of now:

```
'related' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_news_domain_model_news.related',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'allowed' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_news_domain_model_news.deleted = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.hidden = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.is_event = 0 ORDER BY tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime DESC',
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'related_from',
        'size' => 5,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 100,
        'MM' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm',
        'wizards' => array(
            'suggest' => array(
                'type' => 'suggest',
                'default' => array(
                    'searchWholePhrase' => TRUE
                )
            ),
        ),

    ]
],
'related_event' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:dreipc_myadlershof/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_dreipcmyadlershof_domain_model_news.related_event',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'allowed' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_news_domain_model_news.deleted = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.hidden = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.is_event = 1 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.enable = 1 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.sample = 0 ORDER BY tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime DESC',
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'related_event_from',
        'size' => 5,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 100,
        'MM' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm',
        'wizards' => array(
            'suggest' => array(
                'type' => 'suggest',
                'default' => array(
                    'searchWholePhrase' => TRUE
                )
            ),
        ),

    ]
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The by using MM_match_fields working TCA for this both fields now looks like:

```
'related' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:dreipc_myadlershof/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_dreipcmyadlershof_domain_model_news.related',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_news_domain_model_news.uid != ###THIS_UID### AND tx_news_domain_model_news.deleted = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.hidden = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.is_event = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.enable = 1 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.sample = 0 ORDER BY tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime DESC',
            'MM' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm',
            'MM_match_fields' => [
                'fieldname' => 'related',
            ],
            'size' => 20,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 100,
            'wizards' => [
                'suggest' => [
                    'type' => 'suggest',
                    'default' => [
                        'searchWholePhrase' => true
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'related_event' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:dreipc_myadlershof/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_dreipcmyadlershof_domain_model_news.related_event',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_news_domain_model_news.uid != ###THIS_UID### AND tx_news_domain_model_news.deleted = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.hidden = 0 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.is_event = 1 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.enable = 1 AND tx_news_domain_model_news.sample = 0 ORDER BY tx_news_domain_model_news.datetime DESC',
            'MM' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm',
            'MM_match_fields' => [
                'fieldname' => 'related_event',
            ],
            'size' => 20,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 100,
            'wizards' => [
                'suggest' => [
                    'type' => 'suggest',
                    'default' => [
                        'searchWholePhrase' => true,
                        'addWhere' => ' AND tx_news_domain_model_news.uid != ###THIS_UID### AND tx_news_domain_model_news.is_event = 1'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

For that we also needed to add the field **fieldname** to the table **tx_news_domain_model_news_related_mm**

Answer (score 3):

You should give MM_match_fields a try https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#mm-match-fields

here is an example:
https://typo3blogger.de/tca-advanced-mm_match_fields-subquery-sorting/

Comment: Thank you for that